# How shall I perform multiline matching and substitution using awk?

Tags: text-processing, awk, gawk

In a text file, ignoring any trailing whitespace at the end of each line, I assume that if a line is not ended with a digit, then there is a line break between the line and the next line, and I would like to find these line breaks and then concatenate them into one line. For example

```
line 1
li
ne 2
```

There is a line break between the second and the third lines and I should modify the file to be

```
line 1
line 2
```

To find such line breaks, I need to do multiline matching. I does it by changing record separator, but the following doesn't work:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="";}; { if (match($0, /[^[:digit:] ] *\n/)) print $0;} ' inputfile
```

To concatenate two lines separated by a line break, I am still wondering.

Thanks.

Comment: setting RS to the empty string will turn on paragraph mode (records will be separated by runs of empty lines), not 'multiline matching' which is always on in awk. It's no wonder your script doesn't work, because it will just treat the whole file as a single record and print it, terminated by an extra newline (`ORS`). Also, there's absolutely no point in using the `match()` function, if you're not using its return value or the `RSTART` or `RLENGTH` variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run something along the lines of

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=SUBSEP; ORS="" } {print gensub(/([^0-9])\n/,"\\1","g",$0)}' ex
```

- `RS=SUBSEP` sets the Register Separator to a value that is never present in a text  file (slurps the input file to `$0`)
- then do you favorite multiline transformation

Comment: Thanks. Do you know matching without substitution for multiline case?

Comment: I was wondering if this reply doesn't work well sometimes? Why is this reply downvoted?

Comment: Is `RS="\f"` also a working solution?

Comment: This seems to add an empty line at the end of the output. I'm not sure exactly why at the moment.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks. Can you show that it prints an unnecessary empty line versus the normal case that it shouldn't? Is it because of change to `RS`?

Comment: Ah, I see it now.  It prints an empty line at the end because the last line ends with a digit.  Since it ends with a digit, its existing newline character will not be removed.  You then get an _additional_ newline character from the `print` in the code.

Comment: @Kusalananda, Thank you. Last emptyline is the `ORS` (=`\n`) possible fix: `BEGIN{RS=...; ORS=""}`  or `printf` instead of print.

Comment: @JJoao In general, print non-record data with `printf` and records with `print`. Since you're operating in "slurp mode" here (so to speak) and therefore do not really operate on records, it would be appropriate to use `printf`.

Comment: @Tim, > `RS="\f"` anything that is not present in the text would work. (it works find if you text has no form-feeds; otherwise they will be removed)

Comment: @Kusalananda, I agree: `printf "%s", ....` is a nice solution.

Comment: @Tim, > "matching without substitution... ?"  could you give an example?

Comment: @JJoao  (1) I meant tatch only, I guess match() in place of gensub() will work.   (2) for multiline, why not consider `RS=""`? I saw in The AWK Programming Language by Aho used it.

Comment: @Tim, `RS=""`  in awk means: record separator is 1 or more empty lines (it is a special convention -- paragraph mode) In many situations this is perfect... Whatever the record is you can use the usual `match`, `v ~ regexp` `v !~ regexp`

Answer (score 3):

I would address it differently: by looping over the input until you find a "line-ending condition":

```
awk '{ 
       line=$0; 
       while($0 !~ /[[:digit:]] *$/ && getline > 0) { 
         line=line$0; 
       }
       print line
     }' < input
```

On an extended input file of:

```
line 1
li
ne 2
li
ne 
number 3
line 4
```

Or, more verbosely (to see the trailing space):

```
$ cat -e input
line 1$
li$
ne 2$
li$
ne $
number 3$
line 4$
```

The output is:

```
line 1
line 2
line number 3
line 4
```

Comment: Thanks. The script in your reply is very specific to the problem. I would like to see if there is a more general script, which can allow me to specify a multiline pattern and match (and substitute) the matches.

Comment: What "multilne patterns" are you thinking of?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat file
line 1
li
ne 2
lo
ng li
ne 3
```

```
$ awk 'line ~ /[0-9]$/ { print line; line = "" } { line = line $0 } END { print line }' file
line 1
line 2
long line 3
```

This accumulates an "output line" in the variable `line`, and whenever this variable ends with a digit, it is printed and reset.  It is also printed at the very end to output the last line (whether complete or not).

Approximate `sed` equivalent (but with an explicit loop):

```
$ sed -e ':again' -e '/[0-9]$/{ p; d; }; N; s/\n//' -e 'tagain' file
line 1
line 2
long line 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Small GNU `sed`?

```
sed ':L; /[0-9] *$/!{N; bL;}; s/\n//g' file
```

Comment: doesn't work for me?