# Are `match()`, `gensub()`, `gsub()` and `sub()` only concerned about records not fields?

Tags: awk, gawk

In gawk, is it correct that `match()`, `gensub()`, `gsub()` and `sub()` don't consider the fields, and are not affected by change to `FS` and `OFS`? In other words, are they only concerned about records not fields? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those functions all work on a specific string that you pass to the function, or, in the case  of `gensub()`, `gsub()`, and `sub()`, on `$0` (i.e. the complete input record) if you don't supply a string.  They will not split the given string into fields or use either of `FS` or `OFS`.

So, yes, none of these functions are affected by a change of `FS` or `OFS`. They are considering the given string as it is.  If `$0` is used as the input string, this whole string is used unaltered.

This does not stop you from using e.g. `gsub()` on a separate field, obviously.

Comment: @Tim `match()` requires that you explicitly give it exactly the string that you want to match against as the first argument. It does not default to matching against `$0`.

Comment: I guess you mean match() is not concerned with fields.

Comment: Unrelated: may I ask if this reply is wrong? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/481530/674

Comment: @Tim None of them are. They are only concerned with strings.

Comment: "If $0 is used as the input string, this whole string is used unaltered." As far as I remember gsub() and sub() changes $0 implicitly, while gensub() doesn't but return the modified string as a separate string.

Comment: @Tim Correct. By "used unaltered" I meant it's not modified in any way before it's  used. The result may alter the string, but the string is not modified by FS or OFS before it is used by those functions, which is what you asked about.

Comment: Does awk (or gawk) have any builtin function which specifically operate on fields?

Comment: @Tim You can call e.g. `gsub` on a separate field by just saying `gsub(r, t, $3)` (would change all matches of `r` in `$3` to `t`), where `$3` is the 3rd field. So you can definitely operate on individual fields with all string functions.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I wasn't clear. Does awk have builtin functions or operations which specifically work on fields, not nonfield strings?

Comment: @Tim If the current record has been modified in any way, then the `print` function, when invoked as just `print` with no arguments, would print each field separated by `OFS` and it would output `ORS` at the end.  If the current record has _not_ been modified, then `print` would print `$0` as it was from the input. That's the only "special" function that I can think of that actually implicitly does something with all fields.

Comment: @Tim But `print` is a statement, not a function. So I'm mixing terms a bit here.

Comment: Thanks. Why does the target string for match()  not default to $0, while it does for sub(), gsub() and gensub()?

Comment: @Tim The functions `substr`, `index`, `match` and `split` take a string and does not default to operating on `$0`. Why? Well, `substr` uses an order of argument that is already well established from other languages (string, start, length). Others have _other_ things that are optional, like the field separator argument last in `split`.

Comment: @Tim The two functions `match` and `index` are extremely similar in that they return a position in a string where something is found.  `substr` could then be used with the same order of arguments to extract that thing.

Comment: @Tim As for why the language was designed like that, you would have to ask the people that were involved with creating it, or someone who's better at language design and/or API design than I am.